# Alternative to reorder c++ tokens

Tags: c++, coding-style, coding-standards, code-formatting

Our organization is looking to standardize the way we use `const T&` and `T const&` and while we initially looked at `clang-format`  to solve the job, it doesn't reorder tokens so there is no way to swap `const` and `T`.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can reorder these systematically?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Why not use a simple search and replace with a regex?

Comment: So you are going introduce a risk of breaking something by introducing a change which does not really improve the readabilty of the code, just make it a little bit more consistent? Sure it will be worth the hassle?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is worth the hassle. If the answer is sed magic followed by clang format, I'm too afraid of making a mistake by the changing something in a string context or messing up with a const function. If there is a tool that does this already then it might be worth the hassle.

Comment: I'm sure that the more intrusive Clang tools (modernize) can perform this transformation. But I have no experience in using them.